# Cycle from array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cycle

i have an array from SQL which contains language and number how many users use this language.

**Array looks like:**

```
"$languages" => array (5)
12 => "CZ" (2)
4 => "SK" (2)
3 => "DE" (2)
2 => "RO" (2)
6 => NULL
```

As you can see this array is revert. I want to make statistic of them but it's kind a problem for me because only way i can get to this value is to write a count number of it (which is going to change ofc )

```
$langauges[12] -  answer CZ
$languages[CZ] -  answer error
```

Is there a way how i can make cycle from this array to let's say echo it to some HTML?

What i want is :

```
<div>
<div class="country"> CZ </div>
<div class="number"> 12 </div>
</div>
```

SQL looks like:

```
function getLanguageStatistic()
{
    return $this->db->fetchPairs('SELECT COUNT(*), language FROM users GROUP BY language ORDER BY COUNT(language) DESC');
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $k => $v)`

Comment: `<?php foreach($languages as $key => $value){...}?>` `$key` will be the 12 and `$value` will be the CZ. **1 simple question what happens if 2 languages have the same count????**

Comment: Can we see the SQL request ? I think we can do something before using it !

Comment: @Spoke44 Question updated :)
CodeBird I have no clue, if you have any other idea tell me :)

Comment: @Andurit your array won't be useful if you have a same count for 2 languages. You have 2 ways to solve this. 1 either your array key should be the language name not the count, or you used a multi dimensional array where the index starts with 0 then you language and count. example $languages[0]['lang']='CZ'; $languages[0]['count']=12. **Go for spoke44 solution**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, name the row.

```
$request = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as nbr
                                  , language FROM users 
                             GROUP BY language 
                             ORDER BY COUNT(language) DESC");
```

Then (using PDO, but same for others) :

```
$datas = $request->fetchAll();

foreach($datas as $elem){
  echo '<div>
            <div class="country">'.$elem["language"].'</div>
            <div class="number">'.$elem["nbr"].'</div>
        </div>';
}
```

Comment: Spoke, this really start make sense, unfortunately If i use your query code it, my "$datas" dump is blanked

`array (1)
"$languages" => NULL`

Comment: @Andurit: do you use PDO ? Because, I used $this->db->query, maybe you have a abstraction layer between...

Comment: I just found out I didn't call this $request, so fail on my site  (looks i look to this code for too long), anyway this is correct answer.

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

First sort your array with `asort()` tha do `foreach`

```
asort($languages);

foreach ($language as $frq => $acronym): ?>
    <div>
        <div class="country"> <?php echo $acronym; ?> </div>
        <div class="number"> <?php echo $frq; ?> </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But with your structure there is bug:

AZ has 12 users
LT has 12 users

LT overwrite AZ in array keys. Better use this structure:

```
$languages = [
    [
        'country' => 'AZ',
        'number' => 12,
    ],
    [
        'country' => 'LT',
        'number' => 12,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Use a foreach loop to iterate through all the address, as seen below:

foreach($blockIP as $ip)
{
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip){
        echo 'blocked';
    }else{
        echo 'not blocked';
    }
}
If you only need to check to see if the current address is in the array, use the in_array() function:

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $blockIP)){
    echo 'blocked';
}else{
    echo 'not blocked';
}
```

Comment: what address? did you just copy the answer from another question and paste it here?